# how to return a string from easy_curl ? (function used into a dll) C++

Tags: c++, dll, libcurl

i need some help for a project.

i need to create a DLL using easy_curl, i need the use the data form a web site to an other code. 
Here is the code of the DLL

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header_DLL-SIGFOX.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


namespace nmspace {
size_t writeToString(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream)
{
    ((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size* count);
    return size * count;
}

string myclass::recup(string log, string mdp, string id) {
    string usrpwd = log + ":" + mdp;
    string link = "https://" + id + "/messages";
    std::string data;

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, usrpwd.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, writeToString);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return data;
}
```

}

here is the code i need to use the DLL in

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header_DLL-SIGFOX.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;
using namespace nmspace;


int main(){
string var;
var = myclass::recup("53", "8b", "C");
getchar();
return 0;
```

}

and here is the header

```
 namespace nmspace{ 
class myclass {
public: static __declspec(dllexport) std::string recup(std::string loginSig, std::string mdpSig, std::string idSig);

public: static __declspec(dllexport) void recup2();
};
```

and when i use this a got and error :

```
Erreur  LNK2019 symbole externe non résolu "public: static int __cdecl nmspace::myclass::recup(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?recup@myclass@nmspace@@SAHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000@Z) référencé dans la fonction _main  Test_DLL-SIGFOX C:\Users\weved\source\repos\Test_DLL-SIGFOX\Test_DLL-SIGFOX\Test_DLL-SIGFOX.obj 1
```

"symbole externe non résolu" mean : unresolved external symbol

the code is working if i don't use a return and print the var "data" but when i try to return data nothing work :(

if someone is able to help me it would be great :)

best regards

Comment: You have exported ``std::string recup`` but you have not imported it. You should use ``__declspec(dllimport)`` to import that function.

Comment: You were right, I feel really stupid thank you for your help :)